# Filter card list with Razor View

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to make a filter like in AngularJS when u use:

`ng-repeat="u in users | filter:searchBar">`

And your input filter looks like

`<input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="start typing" ng-model="searchBar">`

But the things its that im working on MVC with Razor View and I do not know how to approach this filter.

The list of cards is made with a foreachlike this:

```
@foreach{ var item in Models){
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-container">
    some content
  </div>

</div>

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want this done using angular?

Comment: Nono, I said i was working on MVC with Razor View but i needed something like that function of angular, or any function that do the work.

Comment: @ErikPhilips forgot to tag you

Comment: You can do a search with ajax. What is `Models` ? What is your view strongly typed to ?

Comment: @Shyju  Models is a Model of MVC, just wrote it fast to make the question easier; My view is trongly typed to a IEnumerable<Model>.
I thought about ajax but i wanted the Front-End(Razor View) to handle this processing

Comment: Why use @foreach when u want to apply angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the filtering with ajax. Here is a server side filtering solution.

First, you should move the code which renders the result to a partial view. Let's say you created a partial view called `CustomerList.cshtml`. Move the list code to that.

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-container">
            @item.Name
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now in your main view, you can call this partial view and pass the data to it. Wrap the call to the partial view in a container div. Add a input element for user to enter the search key. Assuming your main view is also strongly typed to `IEnumerable<Customer>`

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>
<input type="text" id="search" data-url="@Url.Action("Index")" />
<div id="div-items">
    @Html.Partial("CustomerList",Model)
</div>
```

Now we need to have some javascript code which listen to the `keyup` event on the search input, read the value of it and make an ajax call to the server where it uses the search key and get the filtered set of data, pass that to the same partial view and return the partial view result.

You can use jQuery `$.get` method

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();

        $.get($(this).data("url"), { searchKey: v }).done(function(res) {
            $("#div-items").html(res);
        });
    });
});
```

Now make sure your server action method returns the filtered data like this

```
public ActionResult Index(string serchKey="")
{
    var items = db.Customers.AsQueryable();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchKey))
    {
        items = items.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(searchKey));
    }
    var t = items.ToList();
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("CustomerList",t );
    }
    return View(t);
}
```

Another option is to do client side filtering. on the items. But if i am going that direction, i would choose a client side MVC framework like angular to do that for me

Comment: I was looking for a client-sided solution but considering that I am restricted to using Razor View I will have to opt for the option of resolving server-sided.

Comment: Razor is server side. The code you have in razor view gets executed in server and the resulting html will be rendered.

Comment: So is it possible for me to use Razor and AngularJS without having any issues? Because Im familiarized with Angular but Im new to MVC and it would be much better to make some things on the client-side like this filtering thing.

Comment: Yes. In that case, your razor view will be a simple place holder which will have the markup needed for angular. Then you will get the data needed for the angular ng-repeat directive, (which is an array) and use that.

Comment: Great @Shyju then Im going to link AngularJS asap to my project. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the variable "searchKey" is different from the view to the controller parameter?

Comment: different in what sense ?